# average of three columns by specific number in a row using perl

Tags: perl

i have an input file with following 5 columns and i want to average the column numbers 3, 4 ,5 individually 3, 4, 5 till its 2nd column value is 5 and similarly for 2nd column value 7 and 2.

```
PHE  5  2 4 6
PHE  5  4 6 4
PHE  5  4 2 8
TRP  7  5 5 9
TRP  7  5 7 1
TRP  7  5 7 3
TYR  2  4 4 4
TYR  2  4 4 0
TYR  2  4 5 3
```

and i want an output like this

```
PHE  5  3.3 4   6
TRP  7  5   6.3 4.3
TYR  2  4   4.3 2.3
```

Comment: is the order (PHE, TRP, then TYR) because that's the sorted order or because that's the order they occurred in the input file?

Comment: its the order that is present in input file

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane'
  $k = join "\t", splice(@F, 0, 2);
  $h{$k}{c}++ or push(@r, $k);
  $h{$k}{t}[$_] += $F[$_] for 0 .. $#F;

  END {
    $, ="\t";
    for (@r) {
      ($t, $c) = @{$h{$_}}{"t", "c"};
      print $_, map sprintf("%.1f", $_/$c)*1, @$t;
    }
  }
' file
```

output

```
PHE     5       3.3     4       6
TRP     7       5       6.3     4.3
TYR     2       4       4.3     2.3
```

Comment: i will try and let know soon if any problem persist.

Comment: thank you very much guys..! its really hard for me to do this

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution mpapec.

I started the the following solution as an experiment to see if I could code something that would only require a single for loop, with no END block needed.  It devolved into 6 for loops instead and a perfect example of how never to code unless your goal is obfuscation.

Yep, it uses an external module.  Yes, it's the stupidist code I'll ever post (I hope).  But at the very least it might get a chuckle out of someone.  And yep, it works!  :)

```
use Array::Transpose;
use List::Util qw(sum max);

use strict;
use warnings;

my $g;
my $l;

print "$_\n" for map {
    join ' ', map {sprintf "%-$_->[0]s", $_->[1]} transpose [$l, $_]
} grep {
    $l = [map {max @$_} transpose [[map {length $_} @$_], $l || ()]]
} [qw(Txt Num Ave Ave Ave)], map {
    my @c = transpose $_;
    [$c[0][0], $c[1][0], map {map {/\./ ? sprintf("%.1f", $_) : $_} sum(@$_) / @$_} @c[2..$#c]]
} map {
    $g && $g->[0][0] eq $_->[0] ? (push @$g, $_) && () : ($g = [$_])
} map {[split]} (<DATA>);

__DATA__
PHE  5  2 4 6
PHE  5  4 6 4
PHE  5  4 2 8
TRP  7  5 5 9
TRP  7  5 7 1
TRP  7  5 7 3
TYR  2  4 4 4
TYR  2  4 4 0
TYR  2  4 5 3
```

Outputs

```
Txt Num Ave Ave Ave
PHE 5   3.3 4   6
TRP 7   5   6.3 4.3
TYR 2   4   4.3 2.3
```

Comment: First I thought that mine is unreadable. :) Perhaps `map` is not good candidate when you change and depend on variables outside of it.

Comment: It annoys me that when doing line by line processing, it is sometimes necessary to duplicate a processing call both inside the for loop when you notice a change in group, but also outside the for loop to catch whatever was left after eof.  Therefore, I chose to play around to see if I could come up with some other construct that would work.  Obviously I took this one a little too far, but considering the OP didn't show any effort, it amused me to create this experiment :)

Answer (score 0):

Script without using modules.

Try this....

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
open(DATA, "<input.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";
my %h=();
my %c=();
print "\n";
while(<DATA>){
    my $temp=$_;
   if($temp=~m/^([A-Z]{3})\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)/is)
   {
        my $key=$1;
        $h{$key}{1} +=$2; 
        $h{$key}{2} +=$3; 
        $h{$key}{3} +=$4;
        $h{$key}{4} +=$5;

        if($c{$key})
        {
                $c{$key}++;
        }
        else
        {
            $c{$key}=1;
        }
   }  
}
foreach $key (sort(keys %h)) {
    #print $key.'='.$h{$key}{1}/$c{$key}." ".$h{$key}{2}/$c{$key}." ".$h{$key}{3}/$c{$key}." ".$h{$key}{4}/$c{$key};
        printf("%s %d %.1f %.1f %.1f", $key, $h{$key}{1}/$c{$key},$h{$key}{2}/$c{$key},$h{$key}{3}/$c{$key},$h{$key}{4}/$c{$key});

    print "\n";
    }
     print "\n";
close(DATA);

______OUTPUT________

   PHE 5 3.3 4.0 6.0
   TRP 7 5.0 6.3 4.3
   TYR 2 4.0 4.3 2.3
```

Comment: i am using Hash for this... if you like to use Array means try two dimensional Array with nested looping(Imagine as Matrix...)